# SQLAlchemy query from multiple tables

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to query from two tables.. my appointments and clients. the client number is my foriegn key in appointments that I can pull from the clients database on.

Right now, I am just returning guests to see what it is doing, I am getting this error:
TypeError: **repr** returned non-string (type tuple)

```
 @app.route('/calendar')
def weeklycal():
    weekyrnum=request.args.get('weekyr')
    guests = db.session.query(Appointments,Clients).filter(Appointments.clientnumber == Clients.clientnumber).filter(Appointments.weekyr == weekyrnum).all()
return
```

render_template(calbyWeek.html",guests=guests)

How can I query everything from appointments and clients with clientnumber being the column to join on (which is defined as the foreign key in Appointments model), and filter by the week?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reference the individual columns from multiple tables in you query, plus make sure you join to additional tables.

```
guests=db.session.query(Appointments.time,Clients.name).join(Clients).filter(Appointment.clientnumber==Clients.clientnumber).filter(Appointments.weekyr==weekyrnum).all()
```

If all you actually want is the guests but use Appoitments in you filter then you also just need to add a join.

```
guests=db.session.query(Clients).join(Appointments).filter(Appointments.clientnumber==Clients.clientnumber).filter(Appointments.weekyr==weekyrnum).all()
```

Comment: I want all columns in Appointments with just 2 columns from Clients.. What is the most efficient way to do this? do I need to define every single column in my query()?

Comment: columns = Appointments.__table__.columns+ [Clients.name, Client.other_column]  db.session.query(*columns)